# Trouble Extracting Model Summary Statistics

Tags: r, list

I am having some trouble extracting some model summary statistics from R.

For examples sake, let us use the `iris` dataset.

```
data(iris)
model1 <- summary(lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data=iris))
```

I would like to extract `r.squared` and `adj.r.squared` from the summary statistics.

```
lapply(model1, "[", c("r.squared", "adj.r.squared"))
Error in terms.formula(newformula, specials = names(attr(termobj, "specials"))) : 
  invalid model formula in ExtractVars
```

I am confused, because the following seems to work fine:

```
model1[c('r.squared', 'adj.r.squared')]
# $r.squared
# [1] 0.01382265
# 
# $adj.r.squared
# [1] 0.007159294
```

Does someone understand this error?  Thanks so much for any help you can provide.

Comment: Can you explain why you feel the need to use `lapply` here?

Comment: try `lapply(list(model1), "[", c("r.squared", "adj.r.squared"))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a need for `lapply` here.  `str(model1)` tells us that `model1` is a list of 11 elements with

```
> names(model1)
#  [1] "call"          "terms"         "residuals"     "coefficients"  
#  [5] "aliased"       "sigma"         "df"            "r.squared" 
#  [9] "adj.r.squared" "fstatistic"    "cov.unscaled"
```

The entire list can be viewed with `c(model1)` The r-squared values can be accessed directly with

```
> model1[c('r.squared', 'adj.r.squared')]
# $r.squared
# [1] 0.01382265

# $adj.r.squared
# [1] 0.007159294
```

or with a regular expression to capture both r-squared values

```
> model1[grepl('squared', names(model1))]
# $r.squared
# [1] 0.01382265

# $adj.r.squared
# [1] 0.007159294
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to @RichardScriven, if you really want to use `lapply` (perhaps because this is a generalization of similar tests): You've swapped the arguments.

You are trying to iterate over a list of model statistics from one run and grab two elements. For example, if:

```
a <- list(x=1, y=2, z=3)
```

then `lapply(a,`[`, c('x', 'y'))` will unroll first to `a[1][ c('x', 'y') ]` then `a[2][ c('x', 'y') ]`, and finally `a[3][ c('x', 'y') ]`, not (I think) what you want.<sup>1</sup>

Two possible ways for you to go.

1. Try `lapply( c('x', 'y'), function(i) a[[i]])` (or `sapply`, for that matter). This is perhaps a bit awkward, though, since it really has no advantage over `a[ c('x', 'y') ]` in the first place.
2. If you are intending on grabbing the model statistics from multiple runs and are simply trying with a single set of statistics, try:

   lapply( list(a), `[`, c('x', 'y') )

   Replace `list(a)` with `modellist` which could have been formed with `modellist <- list(model1, model2, model3)` (or, more appropriately, the return of a different `*apply` function.

PS:
<sup>1</sup> if you try it, it doesn't do *exactly* that -- the output doesn't match -- but it is conceptually how I envision what is going on.